# JavaScript HTML-Blob to Image

Tags: javascript, html, blob

Is there a way to display an JavaScript HTML-Blob as an image e.g. with base64?

```
var blob = new Blob(['html code'], {
    type: 'text/html'
});
```

What I wanted to do is convert the HTML to an image which could be shown on the page itself.

Comment: can you clarify what exactly do you want to achieve ? render html blob to image ?

Comment: Yes, exactly: HTML Blob to Image.

Comment: Hello @David, are you found a solution? I think I have the same requirement than you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902613/save-screen-shot-from-browser